# Why does CSS row hover remain in table with alternating rows (in IE)?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-10

I have a table with rows having alternating colors. Also there is hover effect on table rows. In IE10 under Windows 8 (and in IE9-mode too) the hover often remains even after the mouse is away.

Here the demo (simply drag the pointer from top to bottom over the table): http://jsfiddle.net/rapik/UF8kZ/

Removing rules, which make the row colors alternate, solves the problem.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

---

The CSS source:

```
/*
 * Alternating colors for rows.
 */
.table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

.table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

/*
 * Hover effect for rows.
 */
.table tbody tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me: IE10 on Win7 64bit.

Comment: ON IE9 it also works fine. I also have never heard that someone has this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have Windows 8 and IE 10.0.9200.164666, probably it has something to do with OS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather interesting issue you've come across. An immediate solution is to shift your focus from the `tr` element to its `td` children:

```css
.table tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
.table tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
.table tbody tr:hover td {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This resolved the issue, but may not be sufficient for all instances. I'll continue to experiment with this and see if I can nail down more specific details.

**Update:**

So I suspect this may have something to do with items that have `display: table-row`. I was able to create a `span` element, apply the appropriate `display` rules, and replicate the same issue.

Further Experimenting: http://jsbin.com/asazah/2

Comment: Thanks for the solution! I can see the problem on your example too. I think it is a bug... Did you notice, that sometimes when the cursor is moved fast enough the hover is cleared even from the element with "display:table-row"?

Comment: @Andrej I did not notice that - thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

I too had a similar problem with IE10 not displaying `tr:hover` correctly when the html was dynamically created (but IE10 did appear to work correctly with statically defined html).

```
    div.MenuPanel table tr.MenuOption:hover {
        background-color: rgb(245,245,245); 
    }

 /* work around to get correct display in IE10 */
    div.MenuPanel table tr.MenuOption:hover td {
        background-color: rgb(245,245,245); 
    }
```

The above work around (adding the second declaration with td) fixed the problem!! Seems like a bug in IE10. Without the second declaration, sometimes the row highlights and sometimes it doesn't (i.e. consistently randomly intermittent).